# Connect several RS-232 ports into one

Tags: microcontroller, rs232, atmel

I will have several devices with atmel microcontrollers which I'm going to connect to PC using RS-232. Is there any way to connect several devices into one RS-232 port? (Let's assume RS-232 can handle amounts of data I need to transmit). Maybe there is some other good way for me that is not based on RS-232?

Comment: Try looking at USB to RS232 port expanders. You can get multiple serial ports mapped to a single USB port.

Comment: What do you expect to do at the PC side, do you have multiple applications that will try to open the same serial port? And how would you handle collisions whgen two of your AVrs send at the same time?

Comment: Depends on connection. If devices are connected via multiple RS232-> USB adaptor, I assume that on PC side I will see several virtual COM ports, in case of serial connection it will be necessary to implement some addressing (maybe just append number/serial number of device to each data packet)

Answer (score 1):

Such a scheme exists but it is not RS232, it would be an RS485 system.  Each device connects to a common wire pair and communication is controlled by each device having a unique address.  The main PC system would send a request to an address and only one device would respond at a time. There are RS232 to RS485 converters available.

There are also RS232 multiplexers available that use address schemes, though these are often very bulky.

These days there would be more modern options, such as using addressed (wireless) WiFi modules for communication.

Comment: WiFi doesn't seem to work well when you have 100 devices in 1 hall

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not aware of a mainstream rs232 addressing & collision-avoidance/recovery scheme to accomplish this (though I'm sure you could write one if you really wanted to), USB protocol does have these.

If you connect each rs232 device to a (port on a) rs232-usb adaptor, you should be able to easily accomplish this goal.

Comment: Is there a multi rs-232 to usb adaptors on the market? Didn't know about those

Comment: @user3237732 Off-hand, here (http://www.walmart.com/ip/StarTech.com-ICUSB2324X-4-Port-USB-RS232-Serial-Adapter-Hub/13259214?action=product_interest&action_type=title&item_id=13259214&placement_id=irs-106-t1&strategy=PWVAV&visitor_id&category=&client_guid=c9854a06-0195-4bda-8e9a-f5b9fbde6d42&customer_id_enc&config_id=106&parent_item_id=21899736&parent_anchor_item_id=21899736&guid=57315b21-1ada-4304-a4ed-1b955160509b&bucket_id=irsbucketdefault&beacon_version=1.0.1&findingMethod=p13n) is a 4-port rs232 usb adaptor, and I saw an 8-port model on the 'suggested items' list on that page.